# ReactJS not changing DOM element

Tags: html, reactjs

This is, i believe, a real basic problem. Therefore i don't know why it doesn't work. I have `React` and `React DOM` installed through NPM. 
Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
        <title>Basic Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="height:200px;">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>   
    </body>
    <script type="test/jsx" src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

and here's the JS:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I'm supposed to see a `Hello World` but only get a `Test` inside, thus meanings nothing is changed inside my `div#container`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to transpile the jsx code. Look at this tutorial for a hint. http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html